# What is the best way to use Nhibernate ISession in a SignalR Hub Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, signalr

My Nhibernate session factory is configured to use web as CurrentSessionContextClass. I have a session manager ISessionManager that usually would get injected into the constructor of X service etc..

SignalR does not like this due to async and httpcontext. Do any of you genius folks have any suggestions?

I am overriding the OnConnected and OnDisconnected methods of the hub and was wanting to map users to connections and store them in the database.